# What is the default path on macOS 10.15.7?

Tags: macos

On my mac I have:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

in /etc/paths I have:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Where I can edit or delete this part of PATH?

```
Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Comment: Why would you want to delete it?

Comment: Because I don't where is it from

Comment: If it doesn’t break anything, how about leaving it alone?